# aws kinesis failed to connect service endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I was using aws kinesis to send log data to s3. 
logfile -> kinesis data stream -> kinesis firehose -> s3

I used kinesis agent as a publisher 
So I git clone kinesis agent github on docker ubuntu:20.04 on my local mac os as it appears in guideline 
and ./setup --install 
and set /etc/aws-kinesis/agent.json as

```
{ 
  "cloudwatch.emitMetrics": true,
  "kinesis.endpoint": "kinesis.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com",
  "firehose.endpoint": "",
  "flows": [
    {
      "filePattern": "/tmp/app.log*",
      "kinesisStream": "kinesis-test",
      "partitionKeyOption": "RANDOM"
           ]
    }
    ]
    }
```

and manipulate /tmp/app.log file using python with open

when I cat /var/log/aws-kinesis-agent/aws-kinesis-agent.log
but the data are parsed only and not sent
after some time, when I cat again it said

> 2023-06-13 20:46:50.228+0900  (sender-8) com.amazon.kinesis.streaming.agent.tailing.AsyncPublisher [ERROR] AsyncPublisher[kinesis:kinesis-test:/tmp/app.log*]:RecordBuffer(id=2,records=30,bytes=1169) Retriable send error (com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [UserDefinedCredentialsProvider: Unable to create credentials from user defined credentials provider, AgentAWSCredentialsProvider: Unable to load credentials from agent config. Missing entries: awsAccessKeyId awsSecretAccessKey, EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), com.amazonaws.auth.ContainerCredentialsProvider@: The environment variable AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI is empty, com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@: profile file cannot be null, com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider@: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]). Will retry.

I think it's because of something about credentials 
so I create access key on aws credential site and aws configure on docker but it doesn't help

so I set env directly but it doesn't help too

if need any more information comment to me please I'll trace this question all day

Comment: It works on Ec2 but not on local 
So I think It may have problem on IAM role